# How to search system property from environment varibales?

Tags: java

How to search system property from environment variables?
The task that I have to do which includes this is:-

1. I have to set an environment variable(envKey=value)
2. Then I have to configure the system property in JBoss (JBoss `propName=envKey`)
3. Read this property from code.

My question is how should I map my environment variable which I defined in a file and System property which is in my code?

Answer (score 4):

To access environment variables, you can use

```
System.getenv(variableName);
```

if defined as system properties, then

```
System.getProperty(propertyName);
```

Or to load from a properties file,

```
    String propertyFile = System.getProperty("application.properties");
    File file = new File(propertyFile);
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Unable to load properties file", e);
    }
```